# Is it possible to add an express middleware for a specific HTTP method?

Tags: node.js, express

I want add an **Express** middleware that must be triggered any time a `POST` request occurs (no matters the route URL).

I think that something like this should work:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    console.log('Time:', Date.now());
  }

});
```

But I want to know if **Express** has something out of box to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
app.post(function (req, res, next) {
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html#router.METHOD

Answer (score 1):

Not only is the previous answer correct, but you can also add middleware to specific routes as well, as in:

```
var addCustomField=function(req,res,next){ // assumes bodyparser
  if('object'===typeof res.body){
    res.body.myCustomField=true;
  }
  next();
};

app.post('/path',addCustomField,function(req,res){
  // ...
});
```